# nmap does not find my phone after few minutes

Tags: android, nmap

I want to find out, if my phone (Samsung Galaxy S23, Android 13) via nmap on windows PC on same network by mac address. I will call

> nmap.exe -sP -PE -PA 192.168.1.0/24

with success and I receive list of all devices including my phone, with correct MAC address and correct IP address. All good. But then, I will put my phone on side, let it unattended for few minutes and call same request again. I will see all devices EXCEPT my phone. I still can see phone connected to router. WiFi is established, I can see some minor network activity on pi-hole from my phone. But I do not see it via nmap.

When I unlock phone it will appear again.

What I have tried:

- add --max-rate 100 to nmap params. It seems that it will find phone for a little longer, but still same result.
- turn on/off power saving on phone. Same result
- Set multiple mac addresses. Same result

If there is any setting in nmap or phone or network, I can change it. I am admi

I will take any other utility that works on windows console to search for devices with mac address

Comment: Android phones that are idle with screen off often suspend Wifi connection to save battery.

Comment: @Robert I think, thats the issue, but router can still see my phone as connected. Is there any way how to check for established connections? Or turn off saver on specific wiffi networks?

Comment: Samsung devices are known for their aggressive battery saving features. Not sure if you can disable this, check developer and network connection settings. I know that modern Wifi networks have a new feature for indicating data availability to sleeping devices, not sure if this would change anything but may be worth a check if your Wifi supports it.